# Does this SQL statement require a nested SELECT query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Here is what I have so far but the results are wrong.

```
SELECT c.CompanyName,
       COUNT(o.OrderID) AS [Total Orders],
       SUM(
           (od.UnitPrice -
           (od.UnitPrice * od.Discount))* Quantity) AS [Purchase Total]
FROM Customers AS c,
     Orders AS o,
     [Order Details] AS od
WHERE c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
AND o.OrderID = od.OrderID
GROUP BY c.CompanyName
ORDER BY c.CompanyName;
```

The issue I am having is with the count, it is off by double or more. I believe that this is because the OrderID appears multiple times in the Order Details table. I think I need a nested SELECT statement but I am unsure how to do that.

Would I be removing  the SUM() expression, Order Details, and the AND clause from the first query? Or am I way off?

With help I have gotten the COUNT field to work but now my SUM field is wrong. This is my most recent attempt and it produces the same value for every customer.

```
SELECT c.CompanyName, 
       COUNT(o.OrderID) AS [Total Orders], 
        (SELECT SUM(
         (odIN.UnitPrice -
         (odIN.UnitPrice * odIN.Discount)) * odIN.Quantity) AS [OrderTotal]
         FROM [Order Details] AS odIN, Orders As oIN
         WHERE odIN.OrderID = oIN.OrderID) AS [Purchase Total]
FROM 
     Customers AS c, Orders AS o
WHERE c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
GROUP BY c.CompanyName
ORDER BY c.CompanyName;
```

I was unsuccessful at getting the query to fully work the way I wanted it to. Then I realized that maybe maybe I was looking for the wrong data. So I switched the name for the COUNT field to Num Products Purchased.

I would still like to get the other way working, but I think that will require creating a temporary table or view that could be used to do one of the calculations and then call it from the query. That is something I'll have to figure out.

Thank you for the attempts to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Access doesn't have `COUNT(DISTINCT)` then you need to create an inner query.

What this does is compute the sum of each item in an order in the inner query, and then sums up all the order totals for the customer as the purchase total.  An individual OrderID will not be counted twice, as `o` and `od` now have a one to one relationship.

There might be a syntax error in there somewhere, but the idea should work.

```
SELECT c.CompanyName, 
       COUNT(o.OrderID) AS [Total Orders], 
       SUM(od.OrderTotal) AS [Purchase Total]
FROM 
     Customers AS c, 
     Orders AS o,
     (SELECT odIn.OrderID, 
         SUM(
         (odIn.UnitPrice -
         (odIn.UnitPrice * odIn.Discount)) * odIn.Quantity) AS [OrderTotal]
         FROM [Order Details] AS odIn
         GROUP BY odIn.OrderID) AS od
WHERE c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
    AND o.OrderID = od.OrderID
GROUP BY c.CompanyName
ORDER BY c.CompanyName;
```

Answer (score 0):

if the problem is because OrderID appears multiple times, try:

```
SELECT c.CompanyName, COUNT(DISTINCT o.OrderID) AS [Total Orders], SUM((od.UnitPrice - (od.UnitPrice * od.Discount)) * Quantity) AS [Purchase Total]
FROM Customers AS c, Orders AS o, [Order Details] AS od
WHERE c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID AND o.OrderID = od.OrderID
GROUP BY c.CompanyName
ORDER BY c.CompanyName;
```

The distinct clause lets you count only each appearance.

Answer (score 0):

First I would like to thank Daniel for his help. I did finally get the query to work with help from another source. Daniel's solution is better as it requires less code and even formats the sum in currency.

Here is the one I got to work:

```
SELECT vtOrdCnt.*, ROUND(vtTotCost.PurchaseTotal, 2) AS [Purchase Total]
FROM
(
SELECT CustomerID, COUNT(OrderID) AS TotalOrders
FROM orders
GROUP BY CustomerID
) AS vtOrdCnt,
(
SELECT CustomerID, SUM(UnitPrice * (1-Discount)*Quantity) AS PurchaseTotal
FROM Orders AS o, [Order Details] AS od
WHERE o.orderID = od.orderID
GROUP BY CustomerID
) AS vtTotCost
WHERE vtOrdCnt.CustomerID = vtTotCost.CustomerID
ORDER BY  vtOrdCnt.CustomerId
```

By using Aliases and two select statements in the FROM clause it allowed the query to function the way I wanted it to.